# XSL 0kb when I try add another row

Tags: xsl-fo

I tried adding another row but when I try to download, the file will have a size of 0kb. what is the error on my code? I did not write all the code since it is very long. It is just a chunk of code.

```
<fo:table margin-bottom="10px" table-layout="fixed" border="solid 1px black" width="100%">
                <fo:table-column column-width='=50%' />
                <fo:table-column column-width='50%' />
                <fo:table-body>

                        <fo:table-row keep-with-next.within-page="always" background-color="#DDD">
                                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" number-columns-spanned="3">
                                        <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="8pt" margin-top="2px" margin-bottom="2px" text-align="center">
                                                OTHER SERVICES
                                        </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>

                        <fo:table-row border="solid 1px black">
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                        <fo:block>
                                                Service/Support
                                        </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                        <fo:block>
                                                Agency
                                        </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
```

> ```
>                               //heres the row I added. How come It began as 0kb?
> ```

```
                                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border="solid 1px black" padding="1mm">
                                        <fo:block>
                                                Third row
                                        </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Sorry, no hope of debugging this from the information given. There's a cause, but you haven't given us enough clues to find it.

Comment: Well, as Michael Kay says .. not much hope ... however:
1) <fo:table-column column-width='=50%' />
That is certainly wrong, no way the value of column-width contains an "=" sign
2) You didn't add a "row" as you state, you added a table-cell (the third) in a two-column table